# New MVC field not displaying

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add another column to a table on an existing MVC site by adding the following lines:

Snippet of Model:

```
public partial class viewUserRecord
{
    [Display(Name = "Agent ID")]
    public Nullable<int> agentId { get; set; }

    ...
    ....

    // New code:
    [Display(Name = "Mailing Zip")]
    public string mailingZip { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<tr role="row">
     <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTables-example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Rendering engine: activate to sort column ascending">
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.agentId)
     </th>

     ...
     ....


     <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTables-example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Rendering engine: activate to sort column ascending">
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.mailingZip)
     </th>
</tr>

<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
           <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.agentId) // debugger shows correct value here
          </td>

          ...
          ....

          <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.mailingZip)  // debugger shows NULL here
          </td>
        </tr>
     }
</tbody>
```

This adds the new column to the table but does not retrieve the relevant data.

The model references a database view `viewUserDetails` which contains the correct data for the new field, `mailingZip`,  but debugging through the view shows the contents as `NULL`.

The `Agent ID` field displays fine.

I realise I've missed something but have become stumped.

Comment: your attribute is backwards.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I've edited the Q.

Comment: where are you setting the property values?  where is your controller code where you're building your model?   Your viewmodel has `agentid` but your class has `id`.. you're missing a step somewhere.. we need to see that step also

Comment: sorry, that was another typo - it should be `agentId`.

Comment: Could you check converting database table values `viewUserDetails` to view model `viewUserRecord`. May be you are missing an assignment to that property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions folks but it was an oversight after all.

Turns out the step I had overlooked was the need to update the `.edmx` file to reflect the new columns.

This in turn has proved to be far from straightforward but I'll create a new question if I can't get it working.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried

```
[Display(Name = "Agent ID")]
public int id { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
public int id { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Agent ID")]
```

?

Comment: The agent Id field displays OK, it's the new field that doesn't. I've edited the Q.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.agentId)
```

with

```
@item.agentId
```

Comment: That throws a `local variable cannot be declared in this scope...` error

Comment: However, it doesn't seem to be a problem with the view, would you post the controller code?

Comment: AND the @model line from the view, pls?